# Trouble calling height() on a binary tree

Tags: python, binary-tree, nested-function

I'm writing a function to check if a binary tree satisfies the Height-Balance Property. This is my code but I'm having trouble calling the height function for left and right from my given LinkedBinaryTree class. The main thing that's confusing me is that the nested function takes the root a parameter but height() doesn't. For reference, bin_tree is a LinkedBinaryTree() not a node. Thank you in advance for any help!

**My Code**

```
from LinkedBinaryTree import LinkedBinaryTree

def is_height_balanced(bin_tree):
    if bin_tree.root is None:
        return True
    left = bin_tree.height()
    right = bin_tree.height()

    if abs(left - right) <= 1:
        if is_height_balanced(bin_tree.root.left) is True and is_height_balanced(bin_tree.root.right) is True:
            return True

    return False
```

**Portion of LinkedBinaryTree class**

```
class LinkedBinaryTree:

    class Node:
        def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
            self.data = data
            self.parent = None
            self.left = left
            if (self.left is not None):
                self.left.parent = self
            self.right = right
            if (self.right is not None):
                self.right.parent = self

    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root
        self.size = self.count_nodes()

    # assuming count_nodes() and is_empty() works as expected

    def height(self):
        def subtree_height(root):
            if (root.left is None and root.right is None):
                return 0
            elif (root.left is None):
                return 1 + subtree_height(root.right)
            elif (root.right is None):
                return 1 + subtree_height(root.left)
            else:
                left_height = subtree_height(root.left)
                right_height = subtree_height(root.right)
                return 1 + max(left_height, right_height)

        if(self.is_empty()):
            raise Exception("Tree is empty")
        return subtree_height(self.root)
```

Comment: Make `subtree_height` a method on `Node` (operating on `self`, not `root`, but the exact same implementation), with `LinkedBinaryTree.height()` returning `self.root.subtree_height()`.  That will allow you to also use `subtree_height` in your `is_height_balanced` function.

Comment: @Samwise thank you! Does that mean that I can't call height() in is_height_balanced without adjusting the LinkedBinaryTree class first?

Comment: Yes -- the way you've implemented `height` it's not possible to get the height of a subtree in any other context.  You could reimplement `subtree_height` outside of the class of course, but much easier to just refactor a little bit to make it part of the `Node` interface.